# How do I write bicross product symbols in latex?

Tags: symbols

[image]

There are commands for the top two symbols `\ltimes` and `\rtimes`, however I have not been able to find commands for the other 4 symbols. Is there a simple way that I could create commands for these symbols?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just combine existing symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\blacktriangleright\mathrel{\mkern-4mu}<$,
$>\mathrel{\mkern-4mu}\blacktriangleleft$,
$\blacktriangleright\joinrel\mathrel{\triangleleft}$,
$\mathrel{\triangleright}\joinrel\blacktriangleleft$

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\joinrel` is defined (robustly) as `\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}`. It's enough for the last two symbols; for the first two a slighlty larger value of `4mu` looks better to me.

As a matter of fact, `\ltimes` and `\rtimes` do not yield the "unsymmetric" symbols in your picture. They can be similarly obtained joining `<`/ `>` with `\triangleleft`/`\triangleright`.

```
$>\joinrel\mathrel{\triangleleft}$ vs. $\rtimes$
$\mathrel{\triangleright}\joinrel<$ vs. $\ltimes$
```

[image]

My fantasy isn't rich enough to come up with names for all these `;-)`

Comment: Since the second looks like an alpha drawn with lines, maybe `\linealpha` and the reverse `\lineahpla`?

Comment: [I am new to this site, hopefully this is how I comment]

Thank you for the help! I have gone with Stevens solution, but I have taken inspiration from your response! With a few alterations I was able to improve on the ltimes and rtimes just as you did.

Answer (score 12):

This takes campa's answer (+1) and makes an enhancement/alteration: it scales the result downward to occupy the same vertical footprint as the letter `x`.

Like campa's result, it works across math styles.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,scalerel}
\newcommand\bicrossl{%
  \mathrel{\scalerel*{\mathrel{\triangleright}\joinrel\blacktriangleleft}{x}}}
\newcommand\bicrossr{%
  \mathrel{\scalerel*{\blacktriangleright\joinrel\mathrel{\triangleleft}}{x}}}
\newcommand\biopencrossl{%
  \mathrel{\scalerel*{>\kern-.4\LMpt\joinrel\blacktriangleleft}{x}}}
\newcommand\biopencrossr{%
  \mathrel{\scalerel*{\blacktriangleright\joinrel\kern-.4\LMpt<}{x}}}
\begin{document}
$x\bicrossr y$ and $x\bicrossl y$, 

$x\biopencrossr y$ and $x\biopencrossl y$, 

$\scriptstyle x\bicrossr y$ and $\scriptstyle x\bicrossl y$, 

$\scriptstyle x\biopencrossr y$ and $\scriptstyle x\biopencrossl y$, 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 to you too, but my version already scales correctly in different math styles `;-)`

Comment: @campa Sorry. No slight intended   Revised to reflect this fact.

Comment: None taken `:-)`

Comment: [I am new to this site, hopefully this is how I comment]

Thank you for your response, I've manged to alter your solution slightly to get what I want. :)

Comment: That's great.  This is the way to comment to the giver of an answer.  To comment to someone who is part of the conversation but not the owner of the question or answer, you need to cite them by name, as in @OliverMorrison .  Welcome to the site!